# build system for debug and release and for src directory

Tags: c++, linux

I'm looking for a one file c++ build system for a simple c++ project on linux. The project has src/ and include/ directories. And I need a debug and a release build.

I can do this in one makefile but it's not straight forward and lacks readability.
I tried doing this with CMake, but it's not simple enough. It involves out of source builds and multiple CMakeLists. I guess I could live with the multiple CMakeLists, but I don't like the out of source builds.

Another thing I want is to be able to have easy one liners for debug and release version. For instance on makefile, I use, make debug and make release.

Is there a simpler one file solution that is readable?

My wishlist would also include support for git, but this probably requires its own question. By this I mean that it can combine multiple git/shell commands to simplify things. For instance, let us say you have a version in the CMakeList.txt and you want to both increment the version, push to git and tag the code all with "make release."

Comment: What feature do you need that requires multiple CMakeList files?   Just because you have a src/ and include/ dir doesn't mean you need multiple cmakelists.  Also what does "support for git" mean in a build system?

Comment: Having used CMake for 8+ years I think the out of source building with CMake is one of the best features.

Comment: I don't think you need multiple CMakeLists to do an out-of-source build.  Just run `cmake` from your build directory instead of from root or src.

Comment: @drescherjm and while out of source builds are good, they aren't mandated by cmake

Comment: Fully agreed. My main usage for that is building the same source tree with more than 1 compiler on windows.

Comment: you have all suggested CMake is simple enough. Please point me to or show me a CMakeList.txt that is simple enough. Just saying it is simple, but providing no proof makes me think it's not really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at a few build systems and I ended up using CMake. It's not the solution I wanted, but I gave up and settled.

Answer (score -1):

There a variety build systems you could use. Here is a couple:

- [SCONS](http://scons.org/)
- [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)

Comment: do you have an example of either doing what I asked?